# Pivot table Syntax SPSS

Tags: syntax, pivot-table, spss

can someone help me with any information on Pivot table Syntax in SPSS? I have to change the appearance of my table using Syntax. Basically, in the forecasted table as given by SPSS, it Shows Statistics and Date in Rows and Model in columns. I want Model and Date in rows and Statistics in column.

Comment: look up `SPSSINC MODIFY TABLES`

Comment: Hey, i tried going through SPSSINC MODIFY TABLE. Seems like this function is exclusively for formatting the table. However, I wish to change the appearance of the table. Let me know which function can help me with this? Also, Transpose is not what I want.

Comment: Sorry, don't know enough about this one myself. Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can be done that I know of is by using the OUTPUT MODIFY command. You will find details about it [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_26.0.0/statistics_reference_project_ddita/spss/base/syn_output_modify.html).